# Cancel transaction in Google analytics (add negative transaction)

Tags: google-analytics

I have a transaction with very big revenue. I'd like to delete this transaction, using this link: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1037443?hl=ru
But I can't understand, what data import type I should choose and And what variables should be passed.

Comment: Are you looking to cancel transactions automatically in GA when it is canceled on store? or you are looking to reverse that particular transaction?

Comment: I am looking to reverse this particular transaction (manually)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are going to use Google Analytics hit builder for this purpose.
Follow the steps:

Step 1: You need to have edit permission for the GA property you are trying to do this.

Step 2: Gather transaction data of that particular transaction including shipping and tax.

Step 3: Navigate to hit builder - https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/hit-builder

Step 4: Authorize it with your email.

Step 5: Create negative transaction in hit builder.

As you are already having a transaction, you need to apply negative values of the transaction with the same transaction ID.

```
v=1 // Version.
&tid=xxxxxx // Add your tracking ID here
&t=transaction // Transaction as hit type
&ti=xxxxx // Transaction ID
&tr=-xxx // Negative transaction revenue
&ts=-xx //Negative transaction Shipping
&tt=-xx //Negative transaction tax
&cu=XXX //Currency code
```

You can use any string as client ID.

Fill up the values by adding parameters and your hit will look something like this.
[image]

Once this is filled up, click on **'Validate Hit'**

If the hit is validated, click on **'Send to Google Analytics'**

Note: It will take some time for data to show up.

I have used this on a test account where I had added the transaction using hit builder, never really faced any situation where I need to do it on live. Let me know if this works.